# Express.js: does passing "app" to module.exports need to be before configuration

Tags: module, express

I'm using Node.js/Express and I have other files that I wish to be part of my server, so I'm using

```
module.exports = function (app)
{
//some code
}
```

In my main server file I am configuring my Express server with "app.use". My question is, can I order my code like this?

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
require('./other')(app);
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

with the require before my app configuration? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if you plan on setting any routes inside `./other`. If you are, the order of your routes will be incorrect. Express executes routes from top to bottom. For `express.bodyParser()` to work it needs to come before any routes are set.